# Is "Dave's 40" correct?

Tags: apostrophe

It's Dave's 40th Birthday on Saturday and there have been emails and texts sent with the headline - "Dave's 40".

Not sure if this is correct, can anyone help?

Thanks.

Pete

Comment: I would interpret 'Dave's 40' as meaning 'Dave is 40'. 'Dave's 40th' would refer to the fact that it was his 40th birthday.

Comment: I think about "Dave's 40's" , But i'm not sure , too .

Answer (score 3):

As WS2 commented, the common way to title the invitation would be:

> Dave's 40th

Which will be taken to mean, "Dave's 40th birthday."

If you just wrote:

> Dave's 40

It would be taken to mean, "Dave is 40," which could also work, it would just be a bit less common. You'd probably expect a following line to say something like:

> And he's having a party!

Comment: +1 The term *Dave's* has two meanings. One is possessive (belonging to Dave), and the other is a contraction (Dave is).

Answer (score 0):

It is a contraction of *Dave is 40*.

An apostrophe doesn't just indicate the possessive, it can indicate a contraction.

It is perfectly common in normal speech to shorten *is* to *'s*.  For example; *The weather's hot*, *this food's tasty*.

I wouldn't expect to use it in formal written English, but for emails, texts and birthday cards it is fine.